# Product name, brand and price is not displaying accordingly in page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page `updprod.php` and `update.php`. The page `update.php` displays a list of products beside which there is an edit and delete button. When I click on the edit link, another page is displayed with the name, brand and price of the product to edit with fields name and brand disabled. I need to change only the price.

What is happening is that when I click on the edit link, the name, brand and price being displayed is the last product in the list. The name and brand is not displaying completely as well. If I change the price, my tables are updated accordingly.

The main issue I am having is the product name, brand and price of the product beside which I clicked the edit link is not appearing in the textboxes as it should be.

Below is my `updprod.php` code

```
<?php
    include_once("db_connect.php");

    if (isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];

        $prod_name = $_POST['prod_name'];
        $prod_brand = $_POST['prod_brand'];
        $prod_price = $_POST['prod_price']; 

        // checking empty field
        if (empty($prod_price))
        {
            // if name field is empty
            if (empty($prod_price))
            {
                echo "<font color='red'>Price field is empty.</font><br/>";
            }   
        }   
        else
        {   
            // updating the table
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tblretprod 
                SET prod_price='$prod_price' WHERE prod_id=$prod_id");
            // redirecting to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
            header("Location: update.php");
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    $prod_id = $_GET['prod_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.prod_name, a.prod_brand, b.prod_price 
           FROM tblproduct a, tblretprod  b where a.prod_id = b.prod_id")
           or die(mysql_error());

    while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $prod_name = $res['prod_name'];
        $prod_brand = $res['prod_brand'];
        $prod_price = $res['prod_price'];
    }
?>

<html>
<title>Edit Product</title>
<body>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<br/><br/>
<form name="edit" method="post" action="updprod.php">
<table border="0">
<tr> 
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>
    <input disabled="disabled" 
       type="text" name="prod_name" value=<?php echo $prod_name;?>/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Brand</td>
<td>
    <input disabled="disabled" 
      type="text" name="prod_brand" value=<?php echo $prod_brand;?>>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Product Price</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="prod_price" value=<?php echo $prod_price;?>>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value=<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>>
</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
</tr>
</table>  
</form>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loop is incorrectly placed. you need to move it down as described here.

```
<html>
<title>Edit Product</title>
<body>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<br/><br/>
<form name="edit" method="post" action="updprod.php">
<table border="0">
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$prod_name = $res['prod_name'];
$prod_brand = $res['prod_brand'];
$prod_price = $res['prod_price'];
<tr> 
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>
    <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="prod_name" value=<?php echo $prod_name;?>/>       </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Brand</td>
<td>
    <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="prod_brand" value=<?php echo $prod_brand;?>>         </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Product Price</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="prod_price" value=<?php echo $prod_price;?>>     
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value=<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>> 
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
 </tr>
```

apart from the loop adjustment i made you will also need to rename your element names to include `[]` if you want to handle the list of products that are displayed. for example

```
  <input type="text" name="prod_price[]" value=<?php echo $prod_price;?>>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. On clicking on Edit, all the products are being displayed instead of the one beside which i clicked the edit. And may i know why the names are not being fully displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice right off the bat here. You should be using mysqli instead of mysql_query as it has been deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

**Second, your update query should look similar to this.**

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE tblretprod SET prod_price='".$prod_price."' WHERE prod_id='".$prod_id."';");
```

**It's always good practice to escape the post data when it will be inserted into the db like so.**

```
$prod_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prod_name']);
```

**No need to do this twice.**

```
if(empty($prod_price))
{
    //if name field is empty
    if(empty($prod_price))
    {
        echo "<font color='red'>Price field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

}
```

You forgot the quotes in some of your inputs. Please see the below code to fix it.

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="prod_name" value="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>" /> 

<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="prod_brand" value="<?php echo $prod_brand; ?>" /> 

<input type="text" name="prod_price" value="<?php echo $prod_price;?>" />
```

Without those quotes in the value it will not work properly. That should be the main issue. :)

Comment: Hello and thank you. I used the code provided below but i am having all the products being displayed instead of the one beside which i clicked edit.

Comment: Same issue here. You forgot the quotes in the value. `<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value=<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>>` Should be `<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>">`

Comment: You need to make sure that you are actually displaying the prod_id in the value before clicking the update form. Take a look at your html and make sure it is not empty.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="prod_id[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>"> This is what i have written but is does not solve out the issue

Comment: Ok, what does your url look like when viewing the form?

Comment: When i view the form on clicking on Edit, i am having the list of all the products displaying instead of the product beside which i clicked the Edit link.